# Moving the root partition to another partition

Tags: partition, manjaro, move-partition

**Background:** I am running Manjaro Linux in a 750 GB HDD Laptop with 30 GB root. I had a Win installation but I've removed it now.

Now I want to move my root in a larger space, say 60GB, in another place of my HDD. Now what is the most efficient way to do that? I have separate `/home` and `/boot`

**Note:** I've searched the internet a lot, but they mostly say about *resizing* the partition , or about *lvm* or for server people who want their server running, or trying to move to a whole new drive. All my operation are in one drive and I don't have enough space before and after `/` to expand.

My `fdisk -l /dev/sda` output

```
Disk model: ST750LM022 HN-M7
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: XXXX

Device          Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda6  1109680128 1416878079 307197952 146.5G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda9  1465137152 1465147391     10240     5M BIOS boot
/dev/sda10  732700672  733749247   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda11  733749248  764999679  31250432  14.9G Linux swap
/dev/sda12  764999680  836302847  71303168    34G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda13  836302848 1109680127 273377280 130.4G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the most efficient way, but a way that is easy for the end-user is something like this:

1. Have a Linux system which can boot from an external medium (e.g. CD, USB). – Many installers have a "Try Linux" mode. They are fine.
2. Start `gparted` as root and have a tool with a nice GUI. You can literally cut and paste your partition.

Please be aware: Resizing a partition is gererally safe. However, moving a partition with the source and destination overlapping is dangerous. If the progress is interrupted, i.e. due to power loss, your data will be lost.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I live booted from Parrot OS and copy-pasted my root. I wondered how to tell the OS that it is my root. I booted in my OS, and TADA! it mounted my new root as root .

Comment: This works as nowadays the root partition is usually identified by the file-system's UUID. The file-system itself is not fundamentally changed when the partition is moved by `gparted`.